# Fastest algorithm to get all the tuple groups that has the same N intersections from a list of tuples without duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, tuples, intersection

I have a list of 100 tuples. Each tuple contains 5 unique integers. I want to know the fastest way to find all the groups that have exactly the same N = 2 intersections. If a tuple has multiple pairs of elements that has 2 intersections with other tuples, then find all of them and store in different groups. The expected output is a list of unique lists (`[(1,2,3,4,5),(4,5,6,7,8)]` is the same as `[(4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5)]`), where each list is a group that has all tuples with the same N=2 intersections. Below is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import sample, choice

lst =  [tuple(sample(range(10), 5)) for _ in range(100)]

dct = defaultdict(list)
N = 2
for i in lst:
    for j in lst:
        if len(set(i).intersection(set(j))) == N:
            dct[i].append(j)
key = choice(list(dct))
print([key] + dct[key])
>>> [(4, 5, 2, 3, 7), (4, 6, 2, 5, 0), (9, 4, 2, 1, 8), (7, 6, 5, 2, 0), (2, 4, 0, 7, 8)]
```

Obviously, all last 4 tuples have 2 intersections with the first tuple, but not necessarily the same 2 elements. So how should I get the tuples that has the same 2 intersections?

An obvious solution is to brute force enumerate all possible `(x, y)` integer pairs and group tuples that has this `(x, y)` intersection accordingly, but is there a faster algorithm to do this?

Edit: `[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (4, 5, 9, 10, 11)]` is allowed to be in a same group, but `[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (4, 5, 6, 10, 11)]` is not, because `(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` has 3 intersections with `(4, 5, 6, 10, 11)`. In this case, it should be divided into 2 groups `[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]` and `[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 10, 11)]`. The final result will of course contains groups with various sizes, including many short lists with only two tuples, but this is what I want.

Comment: Every group should have tuples that have exactly the SAME 2 INTERSECTIONS, but if one of the tuple has 3 intersections with another tuple, then it is not allowed.

Comment: Does this code work? Are you asking how to fix it, or how to find the fastest way to solve this problem?

Comment: No the code only returns the tuples that has 2 intersections with the first tuple

Comment: Still not sure if I understand that "same 2 intersections" correctly. So `[(1,2,3,4), (1,2,5,6), (3,4,5,6)]` would not be allowed?

Comment: suppose the intersection is (1, 2), then the 3rd tuple is of course not allowed.

Comment: In your counter-example ("but ... is not") could you "fix" that group by removing the offending tuple, or is there simply no solution for the pair (4,5)?

Comment: Please check my new edit

Comment: @ShaunHan I have a solution but it's not "the fastest algorithm" O(n^2). The "fastest algorithm" would probably involve defining lookup matrixes. If you like I can post it anyways.

Comment: Any solution is welcomed. Right now I don't even have a solution.

Comment: How much memory can you use?

Comment: Are these tuples for a reason, i.e. does the ordering or position of the matching values matter?

Comment: The ordering does not matter. e.g. ```[(1, 2, 4), (1, 6, 2), (2, 0, 1)]``` has the same 2 intersections ```(1, 2)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like how clean @acushner's solution looks, but I wrote one that's substantially faster:

```
def all_n_intersections2(xss, n):
    xss = [frozenset(xs) for xs in xss]
    result = {}
    while xss:
        xsa = xss.pop()
        for xsb in xss:
            ixs = xsa.intersection(xsb)
            if len(ixs) == n:
                if ixs not in result:
                    result[ixs] = [xsa, xsb]
                else:
                    result[ixs].append(xsb)
    return result
```

If I pit them against each other:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import sample

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


def all_n_intersections1(xss, n):
    res = defaultdict(set)
    for t1, t2 in combinations(xss, 2):
        overlap = set(t1) & set(t2)
        if len(overlap) == n:
            cur = res[frozenset(overlap)]
            cur.add(t1)
            cur.add(t2)


def all_n_intersections2(xss, n):
    xss = [frozenset(xs) for xs in xss]
    result = {}
    while xss:
        xsa = xss.pop()
        for xsb in xss:
            ixs = xsa.intersection(xsb)
            if len(ixs) == n:
                if ixs not in result:
                    result[ixs] = [xsa, xsb]
                else:
                    result[ixs].append(xsb)
    return result


data = [tuple(sample(range(10), 5)) for _ in range(100)]

print(timeit(lambda: all_n_intersections1(data, 2), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: all_n_intersections2(data, 2), number=1000))
```

Results:

```
3.4294801999999995
1.4871790999999999
```

With some commentary:

```
def all_n_intersections2(xss, n):
    # using frozensets to be able to use them as dict keys, convert only once
    xss = [frozenset(xs) for xs in xss]
    result = {}
    # keep going until there are no more items left to combine
    while xss:
        # popping to compare against all others remaining, intersect each pair only once
        xsa = xss.pop()
        for xsb in xss:
            # using library intersection, assuming the native implementation is fastest
            ixs = xsa.intersection(xsb)
            if len(ixs) == n:
                if ixs not in result:
                    # not using default dict, initialising with these two
                    result[ixs] = [xsa, xsb]
                else:
                    # otherwise, xsa was already in there, appending xsb
                    result[ixs].append(xsb)
    return result
```

What the solution does:

- for each combination of `xsa`, `xsb` from `xss`, it computes the intersection
- if the intersection `ixs` is the target length `n`, `xsa` and `xsb` are added to a list in a dictionary using `ixs` as a key
- duplicate appends are avoided (unless there are duplicate tuples in the source data)

Comment: smarter approach. *except it doesn't get the right answer.

Comment: oh wait, unless he only cares about the first tuple vs all possible tuple pairs

Comment: Good catch, updating, still faster :) (for those wondering, the `try .. except` block is needed but was missing)

Comment: Edit: replaced `try..except` with even simpler and cleaner `if xss` - no slower

Comment: Why do you repeat the same code three times? (It is the same code, or are there some subtle differences I'm missing?) Just show it once with comments, then the other method as reference.

Comment: Giving style tips @tobias_k? :) I wrote the solution by itself for actual use, wrote the testing script to include it for easy copy and paste testing and wrote the final one with comments just as an explanaion - which arguably could have replaced the first. Feel free to propose an edit if it's worth the effort :)

Answer (score 2):

a simple combinations-based approach will suffice:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

res = defaultdict(set)
for t1, t2 in combinations(tuples, 2):
    overlap = set(t1) & set(t2)
    if len(overlap) == 2:
        cur = res[frozenset(overlap)]
        cur.add(t1)
        cur.add(t2)
```

result:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {frozenset({2, 4}): {(2, 4, 0, 7, 8),
              (4, 5, 2, 2, 4),
              (4, 6, 2, 6, 0),
              (8, 4, 2, 1, 8)},
             frozenset({2, 5}): {(4, 5, 2, 2, 4), (7, 6, 5, 2, 0)}})
```

Comment: This looks good. Can you change the tuples to only contain unique integers and show the result again?

Comment: Won't this add a tuple to the pair-group in `res` if it shares exactly that pair with _any_ other tuple? Try with `tuples = [(1,2,3), (1,2,4,5), (1,2,4,6)]`

Comment: @tobias_k hmm, i feel like we're getting into not clear enough OP question at this point? your sample would yield `defaultdict(set, {frozenset({1, 2}): {(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 4, 6)}})`, which i can see could cause confusion.

Comment: maybe the best solution is to add tuple pairs to the set, then you can suss out from there how to connect the tuples in your examples

Comment: Exactly, and that result is similar to the one OP excluded in the question. The question is interesting, and I think a solution will not be easy (or fast), but it's really not entirely clear to me how to handle different edge-cases.